# How to display contacts in Android using AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-contacts

I'm trying to list all the contacts in mobile. So far everything was working fine, but when I thought of running my code in `AsyncTask` I'm getting nothing on screen.

Here is code snippet

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_list);

    lvCallList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_call_list);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() 
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(CallListActivity.this,
                    "Loading..", "Please Wait", true, false);
        }// End of onPreExecute method

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            getContacts();

            return null;
        }// End of doInBackground method

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            pd.dismiss();

            lvCallList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(CallListActivity.this));

        }//End of onPostExecute method
    }.execute((Void[]) null);
     count = this.displayContactName.size();
    thumbnailsselection = new boolean[count];
}


private void getContacts()
{
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0)
    {
        while (cur.moveToNext())
        {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            this.displayContactName.add(name);
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                                        new String[]{id}, 
                                        null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext())
                {
                    String phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    this.displayContactNumber.add(phoneNumber);
                } 
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
}

 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    /*
     * Variables Declaration section
     */
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        mContext = context;
    }//End of CustomAdapter constructor

    public int getCount() 
    {
        return count;
    }//End of getCount method

    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }//End of getItem method

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }//End of getItemId method

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        return convertView;
    }//End of getView method
}//End of CustomAdapter instance inner class

class ViewHolder 
{
    TextView textviewName;
    TextView textviewNumber;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    int id;
}//End of ViewHolder instance inner class
```

`displayContactName` value using break point at `pd.dismiss();` is

```
displayContactName  ArrayList  (id=830007844896)    
array   Object[12]  (id=830007907208)   
    [0] "Rrs" (id=830007907144) 
    [1] "Fgsd" (id=830007920424)    
    [2] null    
    [3] null    
    [4] null    
    [5] null    
    [6] null    
    [7] null    
    [8] null    
    [9] null    
    [10]    null    
    [11]    null    
modCount    2   
size    2
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code, when I don't use `AsyncTask` then my code works perfectly fine, but when I use `AsyncTask` problem comes.
Please help me to solve this puzzle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: setAdapter must be called on the ui thread, i.e. in onPostExecute

Comment: Sorry while copying to stackoverflow I made a mistake, actually even though I'm not getting anything when I `setAdapter` in `UI` Thred

Comment: @ChethanShetty if you are not getting anything check your `getContacts` method.

Comment: @Raghunandan `getContacts()` works perfect outside of `AsyncTask`

Comment: @ChethanShetty shows us your `getContacts()`

Comment: @Raghunandan Please see the updated post about `getContacts()`

Comment: Ok, use debug, set a breakpoint at the line with pd.dismiss(); and tell us what you see in displayContactName variable

Comment: @Semyon Danilov value for `displayContactName` at line `pd.dismiss();` is `displayContactName ArrayList (id=830007844896)`

Comment: @Semyon Danilov please the post, I've added the value of `displayContactName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, I was trying to initialise `count` after setting adapter, that was the problem, Thanks stackoverflow and @Raghunandan

```
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            count = displayContactName.size();
            thumbnailsselection = new boolean[count];
            lvCallList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(CallListActivity.this));
            pd.dismiss();
        }//End of onPostExecute method
```

Comment: you can directly use `displayContactName.size()` in your `getCount` since its a inner class. You can make `displayContactName` a class member.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot update ui in `doInbackground`. You should update ui on the ui thread. Set the adapter in `onPostExecute`.

You can also use `runOnUiThread`.

Example

To display contact names.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lvCallList;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvCallList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() 
        {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                        "Loading..", "Please Wait", true, false);
            }// End of onPreExecute method

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
                getContacts();

                return null;
            }// End of doInBackground method

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
             ArrayAdapter<String>   arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
             lvCallList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            }//End of onPostExecute method
        }.execute((Void[]) null);
    }
        private void getContacts()
        {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0)
            {
                while (cur.moveToNext())
                {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    aa.add(name);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                    {
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                                null,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                                                new String[]{id}, 
                                                null);
                        while (pCur.moveToNext())
                        {
                            String phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                          //  this.displayContactNumber.add(phoneNumber);
                        } 
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Snap shot on my mobile

[image]

Edit: 2

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lvCallList;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> num= new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvCallList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() 
        {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                        "Loading..", "Please Wait", true, false);
            }// End of onPreExecute method

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
                getContacts();

                return null;
            }// End of doInBackground method

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
                CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this);
               // ArrayAdapter<String>   arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
             lvCallList.setAdapter(cus);

            }//End of onPostExecute method
        }.execute((Void[]) null);
    }
        private void getContacts()
        {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0)
            {
                while (cur.moveToNext())
                {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    aa.add(name);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                    {
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                                null,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                                                new String[]{id}, 
                                                null);
                        while (pCur.moveToNext())
                        {
                            String phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            num.add(phoneNumber);
                        } 
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
        {
            /*
             * Variables Declaration section
             */
            private Context mContext;

            public CustomAdapter(Context context) 
            {
                mContext = context;
            }//End of CustomAdapter constructor

            public int getCount() 
            {
                return aa.size();
            }//End of getCount method

            public Object getItem(int position) 
            {
                return position;
            }//End of getItem method

            public long getItemId(int position) 
            {
                return position;
            }//End of getItemId method

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
            {
                ViewHolder holder;
                final int pos = position;

                if (convertView == null) 
                {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.display_contact, null);
                    holder.textviewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    holder.textviewNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }//End of if condition
                else
                {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }//End of else

                holder.checkbox.setId(position);
                holder.textviewName.setId(position);
                holder.textviewNumber.setId(position);


                holder.textviewName.setText(aa.get(position));
                holder.textviewNumber.setText("No. "+num.get(position));

                holder.id = position;

                return convertView;
            }//End of getView method
        }//End of CustomAdapter instance inner class

        static class ViewHolder 
        {
            TextView textviewName;
            TextView textviewNumber;
            CheckBox checkbox;
            int id;
        }

}
```

Comment: @ChethanShetty i don't see any reason it won't work. see the example. i used your code only modifying at few places. it works fine for me to display contacts names. modify your adapter so that can display contact numbers also.

Comment: @ChethanShetty i have used your `getContacts` method and it works fine for me. check your custom adapter once.

Comment: Thanks, please see my post I've added my `Adapter` too

Comment: @ChethanShetty remove the arrayadapter coz you have custom adapter.

Comment: Problem still continues @Raghunandan

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34219/discussion-between-chethan-shetty-and-raghunandan)

Comment: @ChethanShetty the edit 2 completely works for me. Modify according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't touch views in Non-UI thread. You must set adapter in onPostExecute();

Use this: (Also, I hope that you keep your contacts somewhere, because I don't see contacts variable in your snippet)

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() 
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(CallListActivity.this,
                "Loading..", "Please Wait", true, false);
    }// End of onPreExecute method

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        getContacts();
        return null;
    }// End of doInBackground method

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CallListActivity.this, R.layout.display_contacts,R.id.tv_single_contact_number,displayContactName);
        lvCallList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(CallListActivity.this));
        pd.dismiss();

    }//End of onPostExecute method
}.execute((Void[]) null);
```

Comment: I saw it and I mentioned that - "I hope that you keep your contacts somewhere, because I don't see contacts variable in your snippet"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call setAdapter in doInBackground which is not running on UI thread. You must pass the result of contact loading from doInBackground(..) to onPostExcecute(..) and there you can create a an adapter and set it in the list view.