# Contact list with checkBox, to select for the group mesage

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to make the contact list with checkboxs. So I have to select the contacts to send a group message ; I tried this code but it doesn't work...
What can you suggest to me what to do further to get the contact list.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.cont1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.cont.MainActivity;
import com.example.listo1.Demo;
import com.example.listo1.R;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    String str;
    ListView tx;
    private Contact selectedAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    class ast extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String name, phone;
        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "loading");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.cancel();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, str);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            //textDetail.setText(sb);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            String phone = null;

            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    phone = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    sb.append("\n " + name + "\n" + phone);
                    sb.append("\n............................\n");
                    str=sb.toString();
                }

                phones.close();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(getListView().getCheckedItemCount()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Contact.java**

```
package com.example.cont1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Contact extends ArrayAdapter {
    private MainActivity list;
    // used to keep selected position in ListView
    private int selectedPos = -1;   // init value for not-selected
    private Context context;
    private String[] values;

    public Contact(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_main, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    public void setSelectedPosition(int pos){
        selectedPos = pos;
        // inform the view of this change
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getSelectedPosition(){
         return selectedPos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

        // get text view
        TextView label = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView btn=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        if (convertView == null) {            
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        }
        else
            v = convertView;

        TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text1.setText(values[position]);
        LinearLayout layout_item = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linear);
        //Set the background and text color
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            layout_item.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            text1.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        } else {
            layout_item.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            text1.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }    

        return v;
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="22px"
                    android:layout_height="22px"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4px">
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**rowLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: Saying the a large amount of code "does not work" does not tell us what the problem is. Please update the question to explain what the code does now, what you want it to do and what other things you have already tried to make it do what you want. There is just too much code in the question for us to try and decide what the problem is.

Comment: i retrieve the name and phone number in the textview.But i want to get those number in the listview,to select the multiple number,and sent msgs to those selected number at a time.So mine main motive is for now is to select multiple contacts from the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it's quite complicated to do it with an Async Task but here is a Snippet coming from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17878191/2545832 but a bit more complete (but still quite simple) which is working (I tested it):

Main Activity:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lvCallList;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> num= new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvCallList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() 
        {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                        "Loading..", "Please Wait", true, false);
            }// End of onPreExecute method

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
                getContacts();

                return null;
            }// End of doInBackground method

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
                CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this);
               // ArrayAdapter<String>   arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
             lvCallList.setAdapter(cus);

            }//End of onPostExecute method
        }.execute((Void[]) null);
    }
        private void getContacts()
        {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0)
            {
                while (cur.moveToNext())
                {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    aa.add(name);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                    {
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                                null,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                                                new String[]{id}, 
                                                null);
                        while (pCur.moveToNext())
                        {
                            String phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            num.add(phoneNumber);
                        } 
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
        {
            /*
             * Variables Declaration section
             */
            private Context mContext;

            public CustomAdapter(Context context) 
            {
                mContext = context;
            }//End of CustomAdapter constructor

            public int getCount() 
            {
                return aa.size();
            }//End of getCount method

            public Object getItem(int position) 
            {
                return position;
            }//End of getItem method

            public long getItemId(int position) 
            {
                return position;
            }//End of getItemId method

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
            {
                ViewHolder holder;
                final int pos = position;

                if (convertView == null) 
                {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.display_contact, null);
                    holder.textviewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    holder.textviewNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }//End of if condition
                else
                {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }//End of else

                holder.checkbox.setId(position);
                holder.textviewName.setId(position);
                holder.textviewNumber.setId(position);


                holder.textviewName.setText(aa.get(position));
                holder.textviewNumber.setText("No. "+num.get(position));

                holder.id = position;

                return convertView;
            }//End of getView method
        }//End of CustomAdapter instance inner class

        static class ViewHolder 
        {
            TextView textviewName;
            TextView textviewNumber;
            CheckBox checkbox;
            int id;
        }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/list">    

    </ListView>
```

display_contact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
    <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I saw in your code that you were able to select many items so it mustn't be a problem for you to select many contacts from this list. You've two options : listener on each checkboxes or a long click listener on the list.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the help..but this [ lvCallList.setAdapter(cus);] returning the null exception...why is it,plz make me understand it

Comment: There are two solutions. One is simple : you didn't clean your project and the R.java doesn't work correctly (to clean, in Eclipse, go to Project>Clean). The other possibility is that you didn't copy correctly the activity_main.xml (or not properly).
Also, you have to be carreful if you do not have contacts while testing on your device, I didn't tried this possibility (so create any fake contact)

Comment: Thanks,But i'am running this app on cell phone,and also i clean the project everytime whenever i run it.

Comment: Ok, I made a beta project on GitHub which is working, here is the address : https://github.com/lolobosse/testSO. Then you just have to pick part of it for you own. 
I have just a question, what are you using for android version on you phone to test it ?

Comment: Its jellybeans 4.2.2 kernal version 3.0.31-1329016

Comment: What about the project on Github, does it work ?

Comment: Thanku Thanku Thanku @laurent Meyer its work :)

Comment: Great ! Then check this answer as the right one to close the question ! :)

Comment: @ Laurent Meyer..hahaha not yet,now i stuck in to get these contacts and message from this activity to another activity in the listview,just like whatsapp or other messanger do.

Comment: @user3359315 Maybe, but your question was answered ; make another one if you still need help :) (much clearer for the community which could have the same questions as you).

Comment: @LaurentMeyer hii. How to add search bar  for search the contacts based on the  name?