# Is there any other way of accessing to contacts without using `getContentResolver()`?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

My app is always slow and sometimes crashes because to access to contacts list, I am using `getContentResolver()` which is making my app to run another additional process to main process. Whenever that additional process is running, my app starts to slow down and crashing.

So, is there any idea of accessing to contacts list without passing to that `getContentResolver()`?

Comment: Where did you call `getContentResolver()`? Maybe you lead `context`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3751547/3559908)

Comment: You should use AsynTask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878142/how-to-display-contacts-in-android-using-asynctask

Answer (score 0):

Use [AsyncTaskLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/AsyncTaskLoader) for fetching contact from device, it is recommended because it is asynchronous and also works well with activity lifecycle.

Comment: @Vall0n I am calling `getContentResolver()` in a background service

Comment: @Hitami `AsyncTask` doesn't work in a background service

Comment: @De_Scholar If you are using IntentService then it already runs in different thread, no need to worry otherwise if it is Service then you need to use AsyncTask or Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `AsynTask` to do this work in background thread

```
private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, Boolean> {  
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.e("LS", "Start !");
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                new String[]{id},
                                null
                        );
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                            String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            String data = "Name : " + name + " - Phone : " + phoneNo;
                        }
                        pCur.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            cur.close();
        } catch (NullPointerException | java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("LS", e.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        Log.e("LS", "Done !");
    }
}
```

Comment: this level of nesting is not good. You should check inverting if statements/return early and delegating to methods